# I am Getting Error for @client.event while programming a bot for Discord

Tags: python, discord.py

I am new to programming and just started learning it, I was trying to code a discord bot just for fun but I'm having some errors and I can't seem to figure out what the reason is. The error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Directory", line 7, in <module>
    async def on_message(message):
TypeError: event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro'
```

Here's my code:

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client
keywords = ["Keywords for Messages"]

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    for i in range(len(keywords)):
        if keywords[i] in message.content:
           await message.channel.send("Reply Message")

client.run(Secret.Token)
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the parenthesis in your client constructor:

```py
client = discord.Client()
```

Comment: I have Tried it but still the Same Error